# Return private module exists but no private headers in swift

Tags: c++, ios, swift

I would like to ask this question.
But first a little background.
I am developing a framework with swift, and in this framework I would like to call my C++ code.

So I read a lot on this subject and especially on the [official site of the clang compiler](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#id29)

Which explains us that to make the links between C++ code and a framework in swift it is necessary to use the method of module.modulemap. And declare an umbrella header as well as the headers you want to use.

For that I took inspiration from the excellent article of [Yuliia Synytsa](https://medium.com/@yuliiasynytsia/link-static-c-library-to-swift-framework-as-a-private-module-97eae2fec75e)

I want to specify that I have defined the umbrella header in public and the headers of my C++ code in private because I want it to be accessible only by the swift framework.

Here is how I defined my .modulemap file

```
framework module myFramework {
    
  umbrella header "Path/to/my/umbrella.h"
  
  module * { export * }
  export *
  
  explicit module myModuleA {
      
      header "Path/to/my/headerA.h"
      link "headerA"
      export *
  }
  
  explicit module myModuleB {
      header "Path/to/my/headerB.h"
      link "headerB"
      export *
  }

  explicit module myModuleC {
      header "Path/to/my/headerC.h"
      link "headerC"
      export *
  }

}
```

and here is how I defined my umbrella header .h file.

```
#import Foundation/Foundation.h
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double myFrameworkVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char myFrameworkVersionString[];
```

So to conclude when I try to compile my code Xcode returns me the error "private module exists but no private headers"

I want to precise that C++ code is neither a library nor a framework.
And also i'm on xcode 14.3

Is there a kind soul to help me?

A big thank you to the community.